# VBA script to embedded linked image in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking for a solution to save a PowerPoint presentation as pptx with all linked images in embedded format in order to share the presentation without the linked images. I need this as I am updating periodically the same template presentation with updated images.

First I created the template pptx using "Link to file". that way, the pptx is updated when image sources change. But I cannot find a way to export in pptx with embedded images. pdf works but this does not fit my purpose.

If I use "Insert and Link", the image selected the first time is used if the link is missing.

I tried all potential pptx or related format to "save as" without success. But I am happy to learn if simple solution like this would work.

alternatively, I think a VBA script looping on all slides and all images, and changing the linked images to an embedded images, will be a good solution. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: >> If I use "Insert and Link", the image selected the first time is used if the link is missing.

I don't understand how this is different from the result you'd get by embedding a linked image.  Could you explain further, please?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
Sub EmbedImages()
    Dim slide As Slide
    Dim shape As Shape
    
    ' Loop through each slide in the presentation
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        
        ' Loop through each shape in the slide
        For Each shape In slide.Shapes
            If shape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
                shape.LinkFormat.BreakLink ' Break the link to the original image
                shape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True ' Set the shape to save the picture with the document
            End If
        Next shape
    
    Next slide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Thanks for the script. it works despite I had to remove this line `          shape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True` which was not working. 

I follow the following process: 1/ save my pptx to pptm, 2/ run the macro, 3/ save_as pptx. therefore the new pptx gets embedded images and the pptm is preserved with links).

Many thanks for your help. I am sure it will be useful for other